# @created() gives me crazy results on my xpage

Tags: xpages

strange effect for me: 
a computed text with @created() gives me crazy results:

e.g. creation datetime is: 09.02.2015 21:27
the xpage shows:    07.07.2014 20:47

it is depending of the opened doc (it's not the creation date of the design element), but it does sth I do not understand.

Am I using it incorrectly?

thx, Uwe

the code goes like:

```
                                    <xp:text escape="true"
                                        id="compCreated">
                                        <xp:this.converter>
                                            <xp:convertDateTime
                                                type="both" timeStyle="short">
                                            </xp:convertDateTime>
                                        </xp:this.converter>
                                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Created()}]]></xp:this.value>
                                    </xp:text>
```

Comment: Do you define more document data sources? In this form @Created() returns data for last defined data source (as many other functions without explicit data source reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Created()` returns data for last defined data source (as many other functions without explicit data source reference).

Moved from comment so you can accept my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Frantisek Kossuth solves it (as a comment, so I answer it here): I have multiple data sources defined, and it shows the creation date of the other data source. 
Thank you Frantisek

Answer (score 0):

@Created returns a Date JavaScript object. You may want to handle the conversion of that to a string yourself to avoid variations based on your server's locale.

Howard

Comment: if I give out a print ("created at: " + dt.toString()) on the server it shows me "created at: 7/7/14 8:47 PM". And on a 2nd doc, created at 10.02.2015 10:16, the same date! And on a 3rd, created on 02.02.2015 11:11:00 it prints "created at: 7/8/14 7:33 AM"

Answer (score 0):

try this, if your data source is named "d"

```
d.getDocument().getCreated().toJavaDate()
```

Comment: yes, this works - but I really would like to know what is the reason for these crazy results. They even to not differ from doc to doc in each case, they are docs with the same date (wrong of course), and docs with different wrong date.

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem using only the code you provided

Answer (score 0):

Try using the timezone property and set it to your timezone properly. Date fields (the converters) sometimes behave weird when running on different environments that are also mixed with local browser/machine settings. I documented it here: http://oliverbusse.notesx.net/hp.nsf/blogpost.xsp?documentId=D22

Comment: Oliver, thanks for your post - I also had realized that "1h shift" (or even 1day shift if you only safe the date part) on every safe, at another project. But in this case the result is so crazy that I just want to know the reason for it.